# Download a zip file with PHP in a Mac computer

Tags: javascript, php, macos

I am trying to create and download a zip file trough PHP. My code wrorks fine in all the posible dispositives except in mac. When a mac user tries to download the file the browser raises an "empty response" error after a few minutes. The zip file size is variable but always is near to 1.5Gb

This is the javascript function that iniciates the zip creation and the download is this one:

```
var peticion = ConstructorXMLHttpRequest();
if (peticion){
        disableButtons();
        peticion.open('POST', './php/createzip.php');
        peticion.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        peticion.onreadystatechange = function() {  //llama a una funcion cuando el estado cambia
            if(peticion.readyState == 4 && peticion.status == 200) {
                window.location.href = './php/download.php?az='+id_windturbine;
                enableButtons();
            }
        }
```

The code that create the zip file (without the bbdd queries) is thisone:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
         $url = '../'.$url1.$url2.'/'.$row[0];
         if ($gestor = opendir($url)){
            while (false !== ($entrada = readdir($gestor))){
                if (strpos($entrada,"full.png")!==false){
                    $files[] = $url.$entrada;
                }
            }
            closedir($gestor);
         }
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $fecha = date('YmdGis');
    mkdir('../temp/'.$id_user.'_'.$fecha);
    $zipname = '/var/www/html/temp/'.$id_user.'_'.$fecha.'/images.zip';
    $zip->open($zipname,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();
    mysqli_close($db);
    $_SESSION['zipaero'.$id_windturbine]=$zipname;
```

When this php file ends then, as it can be seen in the js file, the download file is initiated.

```
include('sesion.php');
    $aero=$_GET['az'];
    $zipname = $_SESSION['zipaero'.$aero];
    if(file_exists($zipname)){
        stream($zipname);
        unset($_SESSION['zipaero'.$aero]);
    }else{
        echo "El fichero $zipname no existe";
    }
    function stream($url){
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="images.zip"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($url));
        $archivo = fopen($url,"r");
        if (!($archivo===false)){
            while(!feof($archivo)){
                //imprimir contenido del archivo cada 1KB (kilobyte)
                print(fread($archivo, 1024));
                //decirle a apache que ya puede enviarlo
                ob_flush();
                flush();
            }
        }
        //cerrar el puntero al archivo
        fclose($archivo);
    }
```

Does any one had the same problem before and know how to solve it?
I think the problem is because the createzip.php script execution last for a long time (3 minutes) but I really do not know how solve it.

Thanks in advance

--- Edit with new info---

I tried the code provided by Vivek D. twice. The first one the download started, but then it stopped at 141Mb.

[image: error1]
[image: error2]

The second one raised the mentionated empty response

[image: error3]

The erased window.location.href is './php/download.php?az='+id_windturbine as you can see in the code. (the capture is from the production server)

I don't know if this will help, but this is the code that I use for the AJAX calls.

```
function ConstructorXMLHttpRequest()
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) /*Vemos si el objeto window posee el metodo XMLHttpRequest(Navegadores como Mozilla y Safari).*/
    {
        return new XMLHttpRequest(); //Si lo tiene, crearemos el objeto
    }

    else if(window.ActiveXObject) /*Sino tenia el metodo anterior,deberia ser el Internet Exp.*/
    {
        var versionesObj = new Array(
                                    'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0',
                                    'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0',
                                    'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0',
                                    'Msxml2.XMLHTTP',
                                    'Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

        for (var i = 0; i < versionesObj.length; i++)
        {
            try
                {
                    return new ActiveXObject(versionesObj[i]);
                }
                catch (errorControlado)
                {

                }
        }
    }
    throw new Error("No se pudo crear el objeto XMLHttpRequest");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not Mac / PC issue but browser issue ? Mac's users often use Safari. Maybe can you try with MAC + FF (or Chrome) ?

Comment: Hello Thanks for the answer. Trying to avoid safari we asked the users to use always chrome in all the computers. We also are testing this functionality with chrome in a mac computer an the error still appears.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code.

```
function stream($url){
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: filename=image.zip');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($url));
        $archivo = fopen($url,"r");
        if (!($archivo===false)){
            while(!feof($archivo)){ 
                print(fread($archivo, 1024)); 
                flush();
            }
        }
        //cerrar el puntero al archivo
        fclose($archivo);
    }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer. **Why** would your code solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tryed your code twice and I got two different errors. On the fisrt one the download started, but stopped at 146mb. The second one raised the empty response error. I will edit my question with the new info.

Comment: You need to make changes in the php.ini file for following configurations:
Memory_limit    - 640M
Max_execution_time -  1800

increase the execution time to higher values if it does not work.

Comment: The Memory_limit already is 4096Mb. The max_execution_time is changed dinamically on the php file to 300. I will try 1800.

Comment: It didn't work. The problem seems to be at the code that creates the zip file. I tried to make all without the AJAX call and is the zip one that doesn't work.